# How to add items in a listview from a service class?

Tags: android, listview, service

In my application there is one tab uses sherlocklistfragment containing list items.I wanna add items to that list from my service class without opening the app and when the app is opened that list fetches the items from the service and adds it to the ilst but I can't figure out any way how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can either save the values to a local SQLite db from the service and then retrieve them from the Fragment, or you can bind to the service: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html